# Javascript onclick event starts when reloading page

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, dom-events

I wanted to create a Button via JavaScript through a constructor. Everything works fine, but the `onclick` event starts immediately after loading the page and not after clicking the button.

```
function Button(text) {
    this.button = document.createElement('button');
    this.button.id = text;
    this.button.innerHTML = text;
    this.button.style.width = 100;
    this.button.style.height = 30;
    document.body.appendChild(this.button);
};

b1 = new Button('button1');
b1.onclick = alert('hello');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will start on load, because you call it explicitly with `alert('hello')`.

Better "wrap" it:

```
b1.onclick = function() {
  alert('hello')
}
```

This way you assign a `function` to `b1.onclick` event, and this function will be invoked on button click.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you were calling `alert`, and asigning it's return value to `b1.onclick`.

```
function Button(text) {
    this.button = document.createElement('button');
    this.button.id = text;
    this.button.innerHTML = text;
    this.button.style.width = 100;
    this.button.style.height = 30;
    document.body.appendChild(this.button);
};

b1 = new Button('button1');
b1.onclick = function() { 
  //Handle click here
  alert("hello");
};
```

`b1.onclick` should be a function.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `b1.onclick = alert("hello");`, it thinks that you want whatever the `alert()` function returns to go into `b1.onclick`, so it will run the function and find out. What you want is this:

```
b1.onclick = function(){
    alert("hello");
};
```

This is an actual function object that will be called when `b1` is clicked.